# How to fscanf string with unknown number of words?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a text file formatted like this:

*code subject_name ects*

Where *code* and *ects* are integers, and *subject_name* is a string that can be multiple words long and sometimes contains a number.

I've tried `fscanf(f, "%d %s %d", &code, subject_name, &ects);` which doesn't work because there are spaces in the string.

`"%d %[^\n] %d"` also won't work because the string swallows up *ects*.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: you need to read the whole line and then to parse it. Writing parsers is one of the most common programmers tasks

Comment: How can you tell when ects starts ? If the subject name contains numbers, spaces and a varying number of words, it will be difficult to tell when ects starts.

Comment: Notice that "code subject_name ects"` is a _line_ from the file.  So read a _line_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: read a *line*

```
#define LINE_MAX_EXPECTED_SIZE 100
char buf[LINE_MAX_EXPECTED_SIZE + 2];// Let code read lines that are too long

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)) {
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n\r")] = '\0';  // lop off potential end-of-line
  if (strlen(buf) >= LINE_MAX_EXPECTED_SIZE || buf[0] == '\0') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Line too long/short. <%s>\n", buf); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ...
```

OK, now we have the *line* read and saved as a *string*.

Step 2: Since `subject_name` and `ects` can be a number, let code look for `ects` first since it is one and only one number.

```
  // Start at end
  char *end = strlen(buf) - 1;
  if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *end)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No number at end. <%s>\n", buf); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while (end > buf && isdigit((unsigned char) * --end)) {
    ;
  }
  if (end > buf && (*end == '-' || *end == '+')) {
    end--;
  }
  ects = atoi(end + 1); // or better strtol()
  end[1] = '\0'; // lop off ects
```

Now `buf` has, hopefully, `code` and `subject_name` which can be parsed with user code, `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc.  Leave that for OP.